# Farm installation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-deployment, server-farm, farm-solution

I will install a sharepoint farm in the following days and I am not sure about the number of servers to be used. My company is not very big but, not so small for a single server deployment.

I was thinking on installing everything on 3 servers, one for each tier. As I have read from internet they recommend using two front end web servers. I can afford installing one more server that is not a problem. My goal is to reduce complexity and increase efficiency as much as possible.

Comment: how many users will use it, what services apps you want o configure?

Comment: 60 users, mainly apps provided by sharepoint, just 1 custom app with low complexity

Comment: With only 60 users, I think 3 servers might be a little big. Perhaps 2 servers will suffice (1 Database server and 1 Web / Application server). See this link for more information about SharePoint Topology Deployment Planning: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ravipriya_de_alwis/archive/2013/03/31/deployment-planning-and-topologies-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 60 Users and apps you are mentioned, I think one server farm is enough.If you dont have future expansion and adding more services in it.

I would go with One WFE/App Server and One Database server, this is good for upto 10K as per MSFT guideline.

Please check [this PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/0/7/A07928F6-5153-4E19-B682-B8D28194095A/sps-2013-topology-model.pdf) will give you more idea.

But still if you want to use 3 server farm, then All web application pointing to Server1 or WFE and all Services applications(I.e. search, upa, mms) & central admin will be on server 2 / App server, 3rd server will be your DB server.